# Deleting a contact from a database using SQLite3. Delete Method is skipping the if statement and displaying the else

Tags: ios6, sqlite

I am unable to delete the record. The code looks good and I am not getting any errors on the Xcode side but when I run the application and attempt to delete the record, it skips the `if` and goes straight to the `else` displaying my error code:

```
Error: Failed to delete contact.
```

I've followed all instructions and all other functions work well. I have to use SQLite3 for the delete. What is wrong with the code?

```
- (IBAction)deleteData:(id)sender {
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM CONTACTS (name, address, phone)VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                               self.name.text, self.address.text, self.phone.text];

        const char *delete_stmt = [deleteSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, delete_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            self.status.text = @"Contact Deleted";
            self.name.text = @"";
            self.address.text = @"";
            self.phone.text = @"";
        } else {
            self.status.text = @"Error! Failed to delete contact";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: `sqlite3_step` returns an error code. [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) returns an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DELETE` syntax is wrong.
Please read [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).

You probaly want to delete a record that is identified by its ID value:

```
DELETE FROM Contacts WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Thank you both! This has been very helpful.